# I need to find the difference of multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have seven days that will be filled in with weight i.e 180.  So i need the +/- to reflect the change in their weight from day to day.  For instance I need the +/- to reflect day one and day two then I need the +/- to reflect the difference between day one and day three, and so on and so forth until the end where the +/- will show the difference between day seven and day one.

A1  Day 1
A2  Day 2
A3  Day 3
A4  Day 4
A5  Day 5
A6  Day 6
A7  Day 7
A8  +/-

Thank you I hope i explained it clear enough.

Comment: Welcome on SU. It is a common practice here to state in your question what you have already tried; could you do that for us? Also: your question sounds a lot like homework. Just to help you started: us a formula to calculate the difference (`=A2-A1`) and if you need to copy-paste a formula down without one cell reference changing, use the `$`; for example if enter: `=A2-$A$1` and copy/drag it down, it keeps comparing the different values (A2, A3, A4, ...) to A1.

Answer (score 0):

In cell **B1** type the following formula:

```
=$A1-$A$1
```

and drag the formula down